# Ember Checkbox Select All, or How to set an observable boolean property not tied to a model

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set an observable property for a boolean value isCompleted in a controller that is not tied to any DataStore model as a workaround in an attempt to have a toggleable checkbox and all select checkbox, and I've tried the following with varying degrees of success:

1. http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/display-a-button-to-remove-completed-todos/ and the related JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ULovoJI/1/edit
2. http://poeticsystems.com/blog/ember-checkboxes-and-you and the related JSBin: http://jsbin.com/heqeni/4/edit
3. http://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-toggle-all-checkbox/ and the related JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/coliwiwa/2/edit
4. http://codeflip.przepiora.ca/blog/2014/05/22/ember-js-recipes-checkboxable-index-pages-using-itemcontroller/ and the related JSBin: http://jsbin.com/heqeni/4/edit

Example 3 is ultimately what I want, and has gotten me the closest. The toggle all checkbox works perfectly, but the individual check boxes do nothing. There is in fact something happening behind the scenes, because the bound value is being "updated", the handlebars template updates toggles is being reflected in the total items count, but the handlebars template doesn't update the checkboxes. Likewise, if I check an individual checkbox, all checkboxes are toggled (not just the one I clicked), and the toggleItemCount doesn't add anything. I've tried a number of variations on this, including specifying my own action to handle the toggle on a button, but the template then doesn't update.

```
App.UserAttendeeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
isChecked: false,

  registerOnParent: function() {
    this.send('registerToggle', this);
  }.on('init'),

  willDestroy: function() {
    this.send('deregisterToggle', this);
  }

    });

    App.UserAttendeesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
      /**
       Simply a placeholder array for each child `itemController`
      */
      toggles: function(){ return Ember.A([]) }.property(),

      /**
       This computed property acts as both a setter and a getter. Check
       out the docs for more information on this type of computed property:
         http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties
         http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-all-todos/
      */
      allChecked: function(key, value){
        if (arguments.length === 1) /* get */ {
          /* Executes `if` block on get when the user toggles any of the individual `itemController` checkboxes */
          var toggles = this.get('toggles');
          return toggles && toggles.isEvery('isChecked');
        } else /* set */ {
          /* Executes `else` block on set when the user toggles the actual "Toggle Select All" checkbox */
          this.get('toggles').setEach('isChecked', value);
          return value;
        }
      }.property('toggles.@each.isChecked'),

      /* Get the total number of selected checkboxes */
      allSelectedItems: Ember.computed.filterBy('toggles', 'isChecked', true),
      totalSelectedCount: Ember.computed.alias('allSelectedItems.length'),

      actions: {
        /* Called when each child `itemController` is initialized (initial state/dynamically added) */
        registerToggle: function(toggle) {
          this.get('toggles').addObject(toggle);
        },
        /* Called when each child `itemController` is deleted and destroyed from the view render tree */
        deregisterToggle: function(toggle) {
          this.get('toggles').removeObject(toggle);
        },
        addAttendee: function() {
          user = this.store.createRecord("user");
        },
        removeAttendees: function() {
          var allSelectedItems = this.get('allSelectedItems').mapBy('content');
          if(this.get("isIndividual")){
            this.get('otherFamilyMembers').removeObjects(allSelectedItems);
          } else {
            this.get("group").get("users").removeObjects(allSelectedItems);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 padding-l-0">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "addAttendee"}}>Add Attendee</button>
              <button {{bind-attr class=":btn :btn-default :padding-l-10 attendeesRows::disabled"}} {{action "removeAttendees"}}>Delete Attendee</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row padding-b-20">
            <div id="attendee-users-manual-header" class="flowrow center font-small border-group white font-xs-7">
              <div class="col-xs-1 border light-default-border default-background padding-5">
                <div class="check-all-named-user-container">
                  {{input type="checkbox" checked=allChecked id="allchecked" name="allchecked"}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                <strong>First Name</strong>
              </div>

            </div>
              {{#each attendee in attendeesRows itemController="userAttendee" }}
                <div class="flowrow center font-small font-xs-7">
                  <div class="col-xs-1 light-default-border" style="min-height:34px;">
                    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
                    {{#if checkedValue}}
                    y
                    {{else}}
                    n
                    {{/if}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 padding-0">
                    {{input type="text" value=attendee.firstName placeholder="First Name" class="form-control full-width required"}}
                  </div>

                </div>
              {{/each}}

              <strong>{{totalSelectedCount}}</strong> currently selected
          </div>
```

At a loss, have put 42 man hours into this already.

Comment: Can you create a jsbin for your code also?

Comment: I have successfully recreated the component from http://emberjs.jsbin.com/coliwiwa/5/edit?html,css,js,output